# An interesting puzzle

Tags: probability, puzzle

Here is a puzzle challenge for you:
Suppose $X,Y$ are independent and identically distributed Random Variables. Show that
$$P\{|X-Y|\le2\}\le 3P\{|X-Y|\le 1\}$$

Comment: I think a rough sketch might be that in order to create any significant probability mass in $\vert X-Y \vert$ between 1 and 2, you have to also create mass between 0 and 1.  So, $P{|X−Y|≤1}$ is no less than half the LHS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known as the 123 Theorem, and a proof can be found [here](http://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/123.pdf).